# Please tell me how to solve path to chaincode does not exist

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

What I did: 
Get into the cli container.
Make channel.
Join channel.

What I'm doing:
peer chaincode install.

I want to install the Chaincode which I have made and is on the GitHub.
So I think it can be installed like example02.

I didn't change the code in docker-compose-cli.yaml and others as well.

When I use the command "peer Chaincode install", it says "path to chaincode does not exist".

```
root@7fdb5cf9a746:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# 
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/Gela-Gunp/OriginChaincodeForMe
2019-01-22 07:48:52.599 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2019-01-22 07:48:52.599 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2019-01-22 07:48:52.599 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2019-01-22 07:48:52.599 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
Error: Error getting chaincode code chaincode: path to chaincode does not exist: github.com/Gela-Gunp/OriginChaincodeForMe
```

Maybe I should do something before Chaincode install.
But I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gelatine, in your chaincode install command "-p" flag indicates your chaincode's source path (Note: **local path**)..

It can be like your command, but you should have those directories mounted inside your cli container. Also don't forget to take care of the *GOPATH* env variable :p

Please go thorough the Fabric chaincode reference docs:
[Fabric Chaincode for developers](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html)

Comment: I'll try it from now on!!